# is strlen($userData['comments']) > 16777215 too ridiculous?

Tags: php, mysql, validation

We have a [MEDIUMTEXT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html) column in a database that has a maximum length of ~16 million. Ignoring the encoding and other length differences, is it reasonable to have a validation method that looks something like this?

```
if (strlen($userData['comments']) > 16777215) { ...
```

or do I just take the string and try to put it in the database and let the pdo catch any DB errors?

Comment: big question is what your mysql's max_allowed_packet setting is. that sets a limit on how big a query can be.

Comment: It's not totally ridiculous, but you typically have other limits (max_upload_size etc.) so that you'll never reach that…

Comment: @MarcB You can send prepared parameters in multiple chunks to mysql. (and thus exceeding 2^24 bytes which is the maximum per packet [as the protocol specifies])

Comment: That's quite a long comment. You aren't storing multiple comments for a user in one record, are you?

Comment: If you're not limiting the length of your POST requests you're exposing yourself to memory exhaustion denial of service attacks. So long as your database field can handle the maximum POST size you're fine. This is the `post_max_size` setting in your PHP configuration.

Comment: Over 16 millions chars? This is enough for a book ;)

Comment: @Adam - yeah I tested and the whole text of Alice in Wonderland fits in this comment field with room to spare lol

Answer (score 0):

I would lower the limit in both MySQL and php to a reasonable maximum length for whatever the input is. If you can't alter the database for whatever reason, I'd lower the limit in php anyway.

I can imagine long comments going over 1000 or 5000 characters, but why would you accept anything longer than eg. 25 000 characters?

Comment: hmm - I guess I'm asking if it's reasonable to validate a string length of that size instead of changes to the data

Comment: It's always reasonable to validate before you insert, especially with this maximum size. I can't imagine that you would want to accept a comment with that length anyway, but if you want to, at least validate it.